# Are there any major shortcomings to using Sun's JSP template solution?

Tags: templates, jsp, sun

This is 10 years old, but still appears to be one of the most widely accepted JSP template solutions. Is this still a viable approach for basic templates?

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/jsp_templates/

I've heard some developers discuss Tiles, but from what I can tell the biggest benefit of tiles is that you get nested (composite?) views, and their approach at first glance looks very much like Sun's JSP templates.

At what point would I really need anything different than Sun's JSP templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "basic templates", do you mean used in a context outside of web pages?

Agreed - Tiles is for composite views.  It's a complement to JSPs, not a replacement.

Velocity would be another alternative.